# Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "hello@gmail.com" using 3 possible authenticators

Tags: laravel

When i run the code i got error "Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "hello@gmail.com" using 3 possible authenticators. Authenticator CRAM-MD5 returned Expected response code 235 but got code "535", with message "535 5.7.0 Invalid login or password ". Authenticator LOGIN returned Expected response code 250 but got an empty response. Authenticator PLAIN returned Expected response code 250 but got an empty response."

config/mail.php

```
return [
    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailtrap.io'),
    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 2525),
    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@gmail.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Hello'),
    ],

    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],

    'log_channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),
];
```

.env file is

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=hello@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=****
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

do it like this in your env:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=***
MAIL_PASSWORD=***
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Answer (score 1):

Turn on Less secure app access

[image]

MAIL_MAILER=smtp

MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com

MAIL_PORT=465

MAIL_USERNAME=yourmail@gmail.com

MAIL_PASSWORD=yourgmailpassword

MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl

MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=yourmail@gmail.com

Comment: that was it for me

Answer (score 0):

Each port uses a different protocol, errors like the one you had can be caused by the protocol mismatch.

1. Change your SMTP port to 25 or 465 or 587 or 2525 in .env file,
2. Save and restart the server by php artisan serve.